# Qualcomm based modem Venus converted to ttyUSB0 but not responding forever on fedora 18

Tags: modem, fedora

I've one usb modem qualcomm based, here is my configuration what I've done in the past.

#### wvdial

```
# wvdial phone
 --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
 --> Cannot get information for serial port.
 --> Initializing modem.
 --> Sending: ATZ
 --> Sending: ATQ0
 --> Re-Sending: ATZ
 --> Modem not responding.
```

#### udev

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/option.rules
ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000", RUN+="/usr/bin/usbModemScript"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe option"
```

#### script

```
$ cat /usr/bin/usbModemScript

#! /bin/bash
echo 05c6 1000 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
```

#### lsusb

```
$ lsusb |grep "1000"
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05c6:1000 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device
```

#### /dev

```
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB0
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

#### wvdial.conf

```
$ cat /etc/wvdial.conf
[Dialer phone]
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = #777
ISDN = 0
Baud = 460800
Username = "user"
Password = "pwd"
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Init1 = ATZ
Stupid Mode = 1
```

#### wvdialconf

```
$ wvdialconf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   
WvModem<*1>: Cannot get information for serial port.
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.


Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?

Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial
```

#### wvdial

```
$ wvdial phone
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATZ
--> Modem not responding.
```

I'm using x86 fedora 18.

#### UPDATE #1

#### lsmod

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
option                 29833  0 
usb_wwan               18701  1 option
ip6table_filter        12712  0 
ip6_tables             17745  1 ip6table_filter
ebtable_nat            12696  0 
ebtables               21316  1 ebtable_nat
fuse                   71577  9 
bnep                   18864  2 
bluetooth             275642  7 bnep
vboxpci                22897  0 
vboxnetadp             25637  0 
vboxnetflt             27262  0 
vboxdrv               264146  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
be2iscsi               76220  0 
iscsi_boot_sysfs       15122  1 be2iscsi
bnx2i                  49543  0 
cnic                   57574  1 bnx2i
uio                    14413  1 cnic
cxgb4i                 32075  0 
cxgb4                  97513  1 cxgb4i
cxgb3i                 28034  0 
cxgb3                 130967  1 cxgb3i
mdio                   13244  1 cxgb3
libcxgbi               54562  2 cxgb3i,cxgb4i
ib_iser                32692  0 
rdma_cm                37085  1 ib_iser
ib_addr                13513  1 rdma_cm
iw_cm                  13753  1 rdma_cm
ib_cm                  36713  1 rdma_cm
ib_sa                  23966  2 rdma_cm,ib_cm
ib_mad                 37175  2 ib_cm,ib_sa
ib_core                61976  6 rdma_cm,ib_cm,ib_sa,iw_cm,ib_mad,ib_iser
iscsi_tcp              18016  0 
libiscsi_tcp           19468  4 cxgb3i,cxgb4i,iscsi_tcp,libcxgbi   
libiscsi               44825  8          
libiscsi_tcp,bnx2i,cxgb3i,cxgb4i,be2iscsi,iscsi_tcp,ib_iser,libcxgbi
scsi_transport_iscsi    46616  8 bnx2i,be2iscsi,iscsi_tcp,ib_iser,libcxgbi,libiscsi
arc4                   12544  2 
rtl8187                56256  0 
eeprom_93cx6           12987  1 rtl8187
mac80211              471137  1 rtl8187
uvcvideo               71339  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12840  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13191  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         33259  1 uvcvideo
videodev               91347  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
media                  19720  2 uvcvideo,videodev
cfg80211              170721  2 mac80211,rtl8187
snd_hda_codec_conexant    56642  1 
snd_hda_intel          32539  2 
snd_hda_codec         109374  2 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
toshiba_acpi           18335  0 
sparse_keymap          13343  1 toshiba_acpi
snd_hwdep              13233  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                54700  0 
rfkill                 20452  5 cfg80211,toshiba_acpi,bluetooth
snd_seq_device         13825  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm                81512  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         13710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_timer              23743  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    63247  12
```

#### /var/log/messages

```
$ tail -f /var/log/messages
Jul 13 14:16:43 localhost ntfs-3g[1519]: Version 2012.1.15 integrated FUSE 27
Jul 13 14:16:43 localhost ntfs-3g[1519]: Mounted /dev/sda5 (Read-Write, label "", NTFS 3.1)
Jul 13 14:16:43 localhost ntfs-3g[1519]: Cmdline options: rw
Jul 13 14:16:43 localhost ntfs-3g[1519]: Mount options: rw,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,fsname=/dev/sda5,blkdev,blksize=4096
Jul 13 14:16:43 localhost ntfs-3g[1519]: Ownership and permissions disabled, configuration type 1
Jul 13 14:16:44 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection...
Jul 13 14:16:44 localhost systemd[1]: Started Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection.
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  102.933110] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.081203] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=1000
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.081214] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.081221] usb 3-1: Product: USB MMC Storage
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.081228] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.081234] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 000000000002
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1"
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.132523] usbserial_generic 3-1:1.0: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.132531] usbserial_generic 3-1:1.0: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.132535] usbserial_generic 3-1:1.0: generic converter detected
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.134761] usb 3-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.159122] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost kernel: [  103.160896] USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:17:17 localhost modem-manager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Jul 13 14:17:29 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:17:29 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:17:59 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:17:59 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:17:59 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:17:59 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:18:05 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:18:05 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:18:09 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: dbus[593]: [system] Activating service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' (using servicehelper)
Jul 13 14:18:09 localhost dbus[593]: [system] Activating service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' (using servicehelper)
Jul 13 14:18:09 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: dbus[593]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 13 14:18:09 localhost dbus[593]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 13 14:18:09 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: Launching FprintObject
Jul 13 14:18:09 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: ** Message: D-Bus service launched with name: net.reactivated.Fprint
Jul 13 14:18:09 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: ** Message: entering main loop
Jul 13 14:18:35 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:18:35 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:18:35 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:18:35 localhost modem-manager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Jul 13 14:18:35 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:18:35 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Jul 13 14:18:40 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: ** Message: No devices in use, exit
Jul 13 14:18:47 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:18:47 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:19:17 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:19:17 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:19:17 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:19:17 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) opening serial port...
Jul 13 14:19:23 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:19:23 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Jul 13 14:19:53 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:19:53 localhost modem-manager[720]: <info>  (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
Jul 13 14:19:55 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: dbus[593]: [system] Activating service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' (using servicehelper)
Jul 13 14:19:55 localhost dbus[593]: [system] Activating service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' (using servicehelper)
Jul 13 14:19:55 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: dbus[593]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 13 14:19:55 localhost dbus[593]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 13 14:19:55 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: Launching FprintObject
Jul 13 14:19:55 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: ** Message: D-Bus service launched with name: net.reactivated.Fprint
Jul 13 14:19:55 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: ** Message: entering main loop
Jul 13 14:20:01 localhost modem-manager[1827]: <info>  ModemManager (version 0.6.0.0-2.fc18) starting...
Jul 13 14:20:01 localhost modem-manager[1827]: <warn>  Could not acquire the org.freedesktop.ModemManager service as it is already taken. Return: 3
//here logged because I ve just tried to manually start modem-manager from terminal but the log below says
Jul 13 14:20:25 localhost modem-manager[1833]: <info>  [1373700025.052722] ModemManager (version 0.6.0.0-2.fc18) starting...
Jul 13 14:20:25 localhost modem-manager[1833]: <warn>  [1373700025.057438] Could not acquire the org.freedesktop.ModemManager service as it is already taken. Return: 3
Jul 13 14:20:26 localhost dbus-daemon[593]: ** Message: No devices in use, exit
```

Comment: The device is describing itself as “USB MMC storage”, so it’s probably initially presenting a disk-like device that contains Windows/Mac drivers for installation. You might need **usb-modeswitch** to switch the device to present the actual modem device.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the `modprobe option` command was successful in detecting your USB modem. After running that command confirm that the modules were loaded correctly:

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
option                 24896  0 
usbserial              29576  1 option
```

Also take a look at your `dmesg` log. You should see messages like these if the modem has been detected correctly:

```
$ dmesg
...
usb 3-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1003
usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
usb 3-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technologies
usb 3-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
usb-storage: probe of 3-2:1.2 failed with error -1
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
USB Serial support registered for generic
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
usbserial: USB Serial Driver core
USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
option 3-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 3-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
option 3-2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 3-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
usbcore: registered new interface driver option
option: v0.7.2:USB Driver for GSM modems
```

Comment: Updated my config status, as your said.. see above

Comment: @user1309539 - what did you add to your question?

Comment: oh sorry Im late, the log is too long enough to edit..